# Automatically (re)connect paired Bluetooth devices

Tags: python, pi-3, serial, bluetooth, raspbian-jessie

I have got a RPi 3 loaded with Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie) and I use `pyserial` to send data over Bluetooth to an Android application. Pairing the Pi with the Android device works fine.

For my Android device to connect to the Pi, I need to run

```
sudo rfcomm watch hci0
```

or

```
sudo rfcomm listen hci0
```

otherwise the Android device is unable to connect (because there is no serial port abstraction available for the communication) and `/dev/rfcomm0` is never created.

Once `rfcomm watch` is runnning, the Android device is able to establish the connection and `/dev/rfcomm0` appears. I can start my python script to send data from the Pi to the Android device:

```
import serial
from serial.serialutil import SerialException

def initiate_ble_serial_port():
        try:
                port_ble_tablet = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm0")
                print("Serial port for the Android device initialized: " + str(port_ble_tablet))
                return port_ble_tablet
        except SerialException as e:
                print(e)
                return None

port_ble_tablet = initiate_ble_serial_port()

while True:
        # doing some unrelated stuff
        ble_msg = str(rcv_cnt/10) + ":::"
        if port_ble_tablet:
                port_ble_tablet.write(ble_msg.encode())
```

This works like a charm provided that the order between the different actions is as follow:

`rfcomm watch` > `Android connected` > `python script`

**However**, if you change that order or if my Android disconnects for some reason (rebooting, restarting the application, out of range, etc.) and tries to reconnect to the Pi after some time, the communication is **lost**. That is, the `write` instruction in the above script raises a `SerialException`

> write failed: [Errno 5] Input/output error

and `/dev/rfcomm0` no longer exists, although the Android device says it *is* connected to the Pi. The same problem occurs both with `rfcomm watch` and `rfcomm listen`.

Trying to reset the `Serial` object in python (namely, calling `port_ble_tablet = initiate_ble_serial_port()` again) does not help.

**How do I ensure a smooth, robust (re)connection behaviour between my Android device and the RPi 3?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In short

The problem comes from the python script which does not close the serial port after the Android device has disconnected.
One can implement a mechanism (doesn't matter how exactly you want to achieve it) that reacts to a `Disconnected` message received by `rfcomm watch`. Namely, when the disconnection occurs, you want to

1. Either close the port in python by calling `Serial.close` or kill the python process
2. Wait for the device to reconnect
3. Reopen the port or restart the python process

### In detail

After calling `rfcomm listen <dev>` or `rfcomm watch <dev>`, the Pi is effectively waiting for a connection to be established on `/dev/rfcomm0`.

When the Android device initiates the connection, the endpoint `/dev/rfcomm0` is created and will live forever *unless* the connection is broken by either of the parties.

In this situation, the python script referred in the question opens up the newly created serial interface (`/dev/rfcomm0`) via the `Serial` object abstraction.

Now when the Android device breaks the link, `/dev/rfcomm0` is indeed removed but the python `Serial` object still lives in memory and keeps the port *open* even though the Android device is down. So when the Android device tries to reconnect after some time, `rfcomm watch` rightfully complains:

> Can't create RFCOMM TTY: Address already in use

simply because the port hasn't been properly closed by the python script when the Android device first left.

To circumvent the problem, one can implement a mechanism (does not matter how exactly you want to achieve it) that reacts to a `Disconnected` message received by `rfcomm watch`. Namely, when the disconnection occurs, you want to

1. Either close the port in python or kill the python process
2. Wait for the device to reconnect
3. Reopen the port or restart the python process